# Change keyboard layout on focus

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I've two text fields in a form.  One field is English text field and other one is Persian text field.
Is there any way to change keyboard layout to corresponding language when user focus on them ?

Comment: keyboard layout  means ?

Comment: Yes , just like what happen in OS when you press your Ctrl+Shift !!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426969/change-keyboard-layout-with-javascript