# Change keyboard language by jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, keyboard, keycode

I need to change language on keyboard after push one key (`) to input form.
The same situation as https://www.vivus.ge/register

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            var key = event.keyCode;
            if(key == 192) {

            }
        });
    });
```

I want to make the automatically language switching to fill a form in two different language without swithcing the language of keyboard manually from windows setting (To change the input characters to different language)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the keyboard layout with Javascript. Javascript has no control over the client OS.

What you can do is change the keys, what they do..

An answer to this question has already been set on this thread: 
[change keyboard layout with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426969/change-keyboard-layout-with-javascript)