# I'm working on a multilingual form implementation using react-admin in a React application. The form consists of four inputs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-admin

1. English Input: For this input, I need to type in English using an English keyboard, with English characters generated automatically.
2. Spanish Input: In the second input, I need to type in Spanish characters.
3. French Input: For the third input, I need to type in French characters.
4. Dutch Input: In the fourth input, I need to type in Dutch characters.

How can I achieve the specified multilingual functionality for each input in react-admin?"

I have tried different props of react admin but it did not worked.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/q/60336848/1427878 that seems not to be possible (although that is from 2020, couldn't say if things have changed since then.)